# How to put defs/variables 'in scope' for deeper-stack blocks in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

For context, what I was trying to do is make some context available to some methods, so that I don't have to keep passing it in as a parameter, but that is no longer my objective. Now my objective is to understand how Ruby scopes work.

So:
I'm using active_admin. In some resource controller, e.g. companies.rb, I can do things like:

```rb
  sidebar 'Related', only: [:show, :edit, :new] do
    # debugger
    table do
      tr { th { navigate_to_related :users, company } }
      tr { th { navigate_to_related :teams, company } }
      tr { th { navigate_to_related :groups, company } }
    end
  end
```

`navigate_to_related` is my own code, and it's not important here. The point is that it needs the 'company' object that's being displayed.

What I want to do, best case, is *not* have to pass in `company`, have it 'in context' somehow.  So first thing I thought was to understand where 'company' is actually coming from. It is available in the scope of the above code, though I did not declare it e.g. with do |company| so where is it coming from?

Then I start to wonder, where do methods (or are they variables?) such as `controller`, and `action_name` come from? These are available to me pretty much everywhere; what scope do they actually exist in, why is that scope available to me in the sidebar scope, and whatever mechanism made those things available to me, can I use that mechanism to make `company` available to `navigatge_to_related`?  (I can be the judge of whether that's a good idea or not once I understand the mechanism.)

I've poked around in the debugger, experimenting with the inspection commands of the debugger, as well as `binding`, `binding.caller`, `class.instance_methods` etc. to try to make sense of things, but I can't make sense of it. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a difficult question for me to answer, because there's a lot of "magic" going on in `rails` and `active_admin`. Trying to understand exactly how everything works from first principles can be very difficult. This is why I advise people to learn "pure ruby" before diving too deep into the magic of rails.

Comment: In short though, my guess is that it's likely got something to do with `instance_eval` and/or some dynamically defined methods (see: `define_method`).

Comment: This is impossible to answer since its multiple questions rolled into one. If you want to find out you're dealing with a method or local variable you use `defined?`. If you want to see where a method is defined use `method(:foo).source_location`.

Comment: Thanks to the above comments, I was able to determine that the specific magic involved is `method_missing` There are two maps, `helpers` and `assigns` that contain all these magically accessible values.

It was an indirect find; the suggested `defined?` returns `nil`, not a variable nor a method; so that suggested `method_missing`

Comment: Then, the suggested `.source_location` took me where I needed to be. TY much!